# Replace values in dataframe 1 with corresponding values of dataframe 2

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, tidyverse, purrr

I have two dataframes (tibbles):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_x <- tribble(
  ~id, ~month_1, ~month_2,
  "A", NA, NA,
  "B", NA, 0,
  "C", 0, 0
)

dat_y <- tribble(
  ~id, ~month_1, ~month_2,
  "A", 0, 0,
  "B", 0, 0,
  "C", 0, 30
)
```

I would like ot replace the cells in `dat_y` with `NA` where the corresponding cells in `dat_x` are `NA`. Expected output:

```
> expected_output
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     id month_1 month_2
#  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     A      NA      NA
#2     B      NA       0
#3     C       0      30
```

I tried with `purrr::map2()` but could not get it to work.

```
map2(dat_x, dat_y, ~ .y[is.na(.x)] <- NA) #Error: object '.y' not found
```

Does anybody have an elegant solution for this? The more compact and readable, the better :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat_y[is.na(dat_x)] <- NA
```

Should be enough ?